# Is earning as a cabin crew halal if serving alcohol and haram food is avoided?

Tags: halal-haram, work, alcohol

I'm a male and considering to work as a cabin crew, the problem is, usually the cabin crew has to serve alcohol and non-halal food. So what if I could avoid serving alcohol to the customers -- ask the Non-Muslim crews instead -- will my income in that case be halal?

Please enlighten me? Anyone who have full knowledge on this please answer. Fatwa or shariah law?

Comment: This is a question like yours answered by qualified Sheikh
[http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=140783][1]

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't serve (provided it's *only* serving that you will be doing and not preparing etc) alcohol or any non-halal food, you're all good and your earning is halal, otherwise it's not and it's a sin.

If you're sure you will be able to walk the fine line and pass all such orders consisting of impermissible items to other non-Muslim crew members (those who happen to have no problem in doing so) then there is no harm.

Great care should be taken in such matters because one might end up risking his religious obligations (*oh, it's just of this once* | *there is no one else to serve I am stuck, I'll end of risking my job*).

> [...] And He it is that feedeth but is not fed. [...] *6:14*